# 15 computers + 1 "master" computer = major headache

Tags: networking, server, multiple-monitors, gnome-terminal, lan

I'm here to ask about a research project for the Math department at a university I have been just accepted to work on. The primary obstacle of the project is as follows. The project requires a set of 16 computers total. 15 of the computers will have dual monitors attached. The 16th computer would be required to act as the master computer (or server or hub) and be able to push different information to each monitor. So we're basically looking at one server pushing different information to essentially 30 different monitors. Is something like this at all possible? And if so, what programs, settings, equipment, etc. would be necessary to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance for any assistance in this task!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a few different options. Probably the easiest 2 are:

- Run Apache on the server and publish the stuff to web pages
- Let the clients connect to the server over ssh and use [Forwarding GUI Programs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Forwarding_GUI_Programs)